# Is there any workaround to install Greenplum database on Windows

Tags: database, database-administration, greenplum

Seems like greenplum database cannot be installed on windows. I have a certain requirement for which this would be best if I can install it on windows. Is there any possibility or workaround for this?

Comment: Just an idea: run a Linux VM on Windows, and install it there. But I'm not sure that will perform very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows is not a supported operating system for the Greenplum server.

http://docs.greenplum.org/6-1/install_guide/platform-requirements.html#topic13

Lists the supported Operating Systems:

-Red Hat Enterprise Linux 64-bit 7.x (See the following Note.)

-Red Hat Enterprise Linux 64-bit 6.x

-CentOS 64-bit 7.x

-CentOS 64-bit 6.x

-Ubuntu 18.04 LTS